# logs not getting generated by LoggerFactory

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j, loggerfactory

I am using slf4j for generating logs and using Loggerfactory class.

Here is my code

```
@Override
    public void afterScenario(ScenarioResult result, ScenarioContext context) {
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("The Result of Scenario",result.getError());
}
```

I am getting below output

```
The Result of Scenario
```

but not getting the result.getError()

Below is my logback-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>target/karate.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>    
    <logger name="com.intuit" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="demo" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="mock" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```